# Coefficient interpretation in multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients

I have a question regarding interpretation of coefficient that I've never seen it before.

Regression model : [image]

In this regression model, how can I interpret beta 1? there is partial derivative.. and it turns out the coefficient is -0.5. What does that mean?

Thanks!

Comment: $Y=X\beta + \epsilon$. The model missed $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation of $\beta_{1}$ could be something like this:

Among people with the same level/amount of training who are represented by those included in your study, a 1-unit increase in the value of the "derivative" predictor variable is associated with an decrease of 0.5 units in the age variable (whatever those age units would be - perhaps years?).

So you need to figure out the meaning of your "derivative" predictor variable to make this interpretation concrete. Usually, a (first) derivative quantifies a rate of change - in your case, it's possible that your "derivative" predictor variable quantifies the rate at which salary changes as a function of experience (?). What does a 1-unit increase mean for this type of variable?

What does age represent in your model? Age at promotion? Age at retirement? It must be an age related to some milestone in someone's employment - it wouldn't make sense for it to just be biological age.

To sum up, your model interpretation requires that you understand the meaning of your model variables.